# Drupal 7 Nivo Slider Error

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, nivo-slider

I'm a complete Drupal noob and am currently trying to get nivo slider working on my new site. I've followed the various instructions (mostly from [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ITor-ptI9aA&list=PL708F0EEDA6735005&index=4&feature=plpp_video)) and added the module but when I get to the end of the process when the slider should be working I instead get my images stacked one on top of another and in the debug console the message "vns.nivoSlider is not a function".

I've used Nivo slider on non-Drupal sites before and I know how easy it should be, anyone have any ideas what's going wrong here?!

Update: I uninstalled and reinstalled all Drupal modules associated with Nivo Slider and now it works! Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you may not have inserted the necessary javascript file(s) OR inserted them AFTER the code is being executed on the page. Can you provide a link to the page in question so to help determine if that is the cause?

Comment: Sorry, I can't link to the page due to client confidentiality. I've not inserted any javascript files as that's handled by the nivo slider module installation.

Comment: Which version from https://drupal.org/project/views_nivo_slider did you download and install?

Comment: 7.x-3.x-dev I realise it's a dev version, but the client specified Drupal 7 :(

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue in  Nivo Slider on Drupal 7. I didn't read the module's documentation at first but it looks like Nivo Slider's library isn't included in the package, it means you need to upload it manually.you can check documentation : https://www.drupal.org/project/views_nivo_slider

```
install/enable Library API
download Nivo Slider libs from https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Slider/downloads
unzip the archive to sites/all/libraries/nivo-slider
```

After completed above process flush the case.
Hope it will work for you.